# Using ui.chart.image.series reducer with higher max pixel limit in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series

Is it possible to use the ui.Chart.image.series function with an image collection, region, reducer, scale, AND a max pixel limit?

I'm dealing with 10m Sentinel-1 data, and even moderately sized regions hit the 1e7 default pixel count limit.

Anyway to override this in the time series plotting function?

I know how to do so using the "maxPixels:" argument in the image.ReduceRegion function.  Essentially I want something like this

```
print(ui.Chart.image.series(collection, polygon, ee.Reducer.count(maxPixels: 1e12), 10));
```

Comment: I have met the same problem. I also watched the tutorial video but I didn't have any clue. Could you please update your answer to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print more than 5000 things.  That includes charts.  To export time series of more data (and optionally chart them elsewhere), please see [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials#tables-and-vectors).